# How to stop 'flickering' in a timelapse created from a set of photo?

Tags: timelapse, fujifilm-x-t20

I use a Fujifilm XT20 to shoot at the sky every 5 seconds.

Here is the final video:

https://youtu.be/vkQ4C5nGw5M

The problem is that in the last 10 seconds of the video the brightness was just all over the place.

I were using automatic aperture and automatic shutter speed.

Then I use `ffmpeg` on MacOS to create the video using the JPEG files

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob  -i  "DSCF*.JPG" -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile baseline  output.mp4
```

I think the problem is caused by the changing (decreasing) ambient light as the sun set.

Is there any way I can do to reduce the flickering in the final video? e.g. during the time the photo are shot or before the creation of the final video

Comment: Try using manual White balance, and you could correct the white balance in a video editing software.

Answer (score 5):

Everything should be set to manual, nothing should be automatic. What's happening is the camera is trying to compensate/adjust for each and every frame. Turn off any setting that would automatically adjust anything.

I made one once, I thought I had everything set correctly and when I rendered it to video it did the same light variance/flickering that you are having with this one.

I checked everything and realized that some of the frames had different exposure values. I then checked my camera and sure enough I had left it set to Auto ISO. That one setting caused the flickering and choppiness.